# c++ callbacks - compile time alternatives to virtual functions

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I want a generically reusable class to be able to perform a callback. I've usually used a virtual function to do this:

The generic class:

```
class LibraryClass
{
private:
    virtual void SomeCallback(){}
};
```

The code using the generic class:

```
class AppClass;

class LibraryClassWrapper: public LibraryClass
{
public:
    LibraryClassWrapper(AppClass& appClass):appClass_(appClass){}
private:
    virtual void SomeCallback();
    AppClass& appClass_;
};

class AppClass
{
public:
    AppClass():libraryClassWrapper_(*this){}
    void handleCallbackFromLibraryClass()
    {
        std::cout << "Handling callback" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    LibraryClassWrapper libraryClassWrapper_;
};

void LibraryClassWrapper::SomeCallback()
{
    appClass_.handleCallbackFromLibraryClass();
}
```

This seems an awful lot of boilerplate just to wire up a callback. The alternative would be to use a functor, which might be a bit cleaner.

But it occurs to me that quite a lot is known about at compile time. Can this be simplified such that the callback is resolved at compile time?

Comment: If you want a callback, then use a `std::function`, not a class with a virtual member. Well, or Boost.Signal.

Comment: Can't see how virtual function is used in your example.

Comment: I take it that the idea is that you need to pass LibraryClass instances to whatever can trigger a callback. AppClass would probably pass it's libraryClassWrapper_ member to that something. LibraryClassWrapper would appear to be a helper class (possibly private to AppClass) to avoid AppClass needing to derive from LibraryClass.

Comment: @bleep-bloop: pretty much. I can't derive from LibraryClass because there are several instances of it. (Also, AppClass Is Not A LibraryClass, so deriving from it would be less than satisfactory.)

Comment: @Sergius: LibraryClass could be a state machine, and SomeCallback() could be called on state transition. Other methods could feed input into the state machine. If I can think of a way of fleshing the example out without unduly cluttering it, I will do.

Answer (score 5):

You can use **[Curiously recurring template pattern(CRTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)** to implement static polymorphism.

Comment: I considered this, but rejected it because the implementation of LibraryClass is typically in a separate file. It's possible that I could wrap LibraryClass with a CRTP template though. Something to look into.

Answer (score 3):

You might find just a simple use of std::function will do the trick. That way clients can implement their classes however they see fit rather than being forced into using inheritance.

This is also preferable over a C style callback which often requires a `void*` "user data" pointer in order to be able to function correctly with classes that want to use a member function.

You can use a lambda to capture whatever state you need and can let the interface of the callback reflect only what is relevant to the notification. Should be as simple as something like this:

```
#include <functional>

typedef std::function<void()> CallbackType;

struct Example
{
    void CallbackHandler()
    {
        /* do something */
    }
};

void FreeFunctionHandler()
{
    /* do something */
}

// Use lambda to call member function of 'example'
Example example;
CallbackType callback1 = [&example]() { example.CallbackHandler(); };

// Use free function
CallbackType callback2 = FreeFunctionHandler;

// Execute callbacks
callback1();
callback2();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think policy based design is what you're looking for:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design

The basic pattern was outlined in Alexandrescu's "Modern C++ Design", and was used in the companion library, "Loki". Given this, the Loki library itself is a great reference for how to use design by policy. The library is on sourceforge here:

http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/index.php?n=Main.HomePage